# Multiple interfaces inside a class for constants

Tags: java

Is it a good practice of declaring constants belonging to different layers say Controller, Services, DAO etc inside a single interface using multiple interfaces for segregation of the constants as per the layer they belongs to for example as below:

```
public interface TestConstants
{
    interface UIConstants
    {
        public static String FIRST_UI_CONSTANT = "FIRST";
        public static String SECOND_UI_CONSTANT = "SECOND";
    }

    interface ServiceConstants
    {
        public static String FIRST_SVC_CONSTANT = "FIRST";
        public static String SECOND_SVC_CONSTANT = "SECOND";
    }

    interface DAOConstants
    {
        public static String FIRST_DAO_CONSTANT = "FIRST";
        public static String SECOND_DAO_CONSTANT = "SECOND";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `interfaces` should be used to define *contracts* and not *constants*. Use an Enum to define constants, if you can't use Enums, use normal java class which is marked as `final` and has a private constructor and define all fields / constants as `public static final`.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar agreed. This is exactly what is described in Effective Java 2nd Ed Item 19 "Use interfaces only to define types".

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need those constants? For what are you using them?

Comment: @All: Apologies just updated my question.. Multiple interfaces inside a interface.

Comment: Same comment: don't use interfaces for this. Use final, non-instantiable, static (if nested) classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks pretty isn't it. A kind of coloring system construction.

However it has its drawbacks.

1. The constants are copied into the importing class, and the imports disappear from the .class file. This means that when the interface file is changed, the compiler might not recompile the importing class (a dumb short-coming of the compiler), and work with an old constant value. Now constant values are not often changed, and a "clean project" easily invoked manually.
2. Then this interface is probably often changed, as it unites several aspects. That is bad style: too much unneeded coupling. More version control merges, more frequent vcs updates needed, more recompilation.
3. And lastly the interface makes it tempting to use constants. Constants are not object oriented (enums can be OO). Having many conditional case-branches is a bad sign. The architecture should be more modelling. Constants do not even allow modular visibility. Also primitive types like int and String should sometimes better be wrapped in their own value class (calculations, validation, normalization).
4. Much can be said for local constants, a kind of Don't-Repeat-Yourself support, smallest modularity.

That all said, having multiple interfaces, acting like namespaces, is much better than mixing constants for different purposes. You should introduce and communicate a consistent usage though.

Your example with redundant names (interface name repeats in constant name) would be for a style:

```
class C implements TestConstants.UIConstants;
    ... FIRST_UI_CONSTANT
```

Personally I would prefer

```
class C implements TestConstants;
    ... UIConstants.FIRST
```

Above still an enum would be nicer.